# Meiosis I or II

Tags: reproduction

Suppose an organism has 8 chromosomes.  When the female and male organisms mate,  how many chromosomes will the mother contribute to the offspring? Why?

Comment: Same issue as [this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/q/21443/8517). We're not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: @MikeTaylor This likely IS a homework question. However, this person DOES NOT SPECIFICALLY SAY IT IS A HOMEWORK QUESTION!

Comment: @L.B. If is not, then I'm sure Camille would be happy to clarify her questions for us. :)

Answer (score 1):

Both the male and the female would give half of the total number of chromosomes for their species (assuming both cells are normal). So if the organism has a total of 8 chromosomes, the mother and father would each give 4.